# Faster i2ccmd execution

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am facing One problem regarding system command execution ?

Actually there are 2 playback music sources like Bluetooth and other source . For that we used one specific codec (NPCA110B) in our system .
To play music on One source , Let consider BT , I have to run 20 command to play music over BT .
One Important Note is, for performing source switch between Music sources , I have to run the 20 commands in sequentially.

In My code , In one of the API , I am giving 20 system command in following way. This API is responsible for doing source switch.

```
void func()
{
        // here 20 commands are there .
        system("i2ccmd w 0x73 0x00 0x02 0xA5 0x00");
        system("i2ccmd w 0x73 0x00 0x02 0xC3 0x00");
        system("i2ccmd w 0x73 0x00 0x02 0xA4 0x11");
        system("i2ccmd w 0x73 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00");
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
        system("i2ccmd w 0x73 0x00 0x02 0xA5 0x00");
}
```

The problem is , I able to do source switch successfully , but performance is Hampering. because i2ccmd internally perform file operation for each command . And execution time is more to execute above command sequentially.

Is there any way to write all 20 i2ccmd in single file operation ? Or any other way to make faster execution of i2ccmd ?

Comment: Perhaps you can make your program "better" by *not* using `system` or external commands? Instead use the I2C device directly to send the data from your program.

Comment: what else option or external command we can use ?

Comment: Hello Guys, anyone have solution on this like any other external commands ?

Comment: Assuming that `i2ccmd` is open-source, you could download the source code to look at what it does. Then you could implement it yourself, to communicate directly with the device without having to go through external programs.